# I wanted to create a cucumer java project to run ui test cases

Tags: android, automated-tests, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm

facing an error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcucumber/runtime/ClassFinder;
at io.cucumber.junit.CucumberJUnitRunnerBuilder.runnerForClass(CucumberJUnitRunnerBuilder.java:11)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)

my build.gradle file is

```
buildscript {
    repositories{
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
    }
}
plugins {
//    id 'com.android.application'
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    sourceSets {

//        main{
//            manifest.srcfile 'main/AndroidManifest.xml'
//        }
        test{
            resources{
                srcDirs=['src/test/resources']
            }
        }
        androidTest {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/assets']
            java.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/resources']
            assets.srcDirs += files('src/androidTest/resources')
        }
    }
//    namespace 'com.example.cucumberuitest'
    compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cucumberuitest"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
//        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        testInstrumentationRunner "io.cucumber.android.runner.CucumberAndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file(rootDir.path + "/keystore/debug.keystore")
        }
        platform {
            storeFile file(rootDir.path + "/keystore/samsung_test.keystore")
            storePassword "android"
            keyAlias "platform"
            keyPassword "android"
        }
        release {
            storeFile file(rootDir.path + "/keystore/samsung_test.keystore")
            storePassword "android"
            keyAlias "testkey"
            keyPassword "android"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
//            signingConfig signingConfigs.platform
            crunchPngs false
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            crunchPngs false
//           signingConfig signingConfigs.platform
        }
    }
//    buildTypes {
//        release {
//            minifyEnabled false
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
//        }
//    }
    compileOptions {
        //made 11 from 1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
//    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//    implementation fileTree(include: ['secstatslog-settings_intermediates.jar'], dir: rootDir.path + '/external')
//    implementation fileTree(include: ['com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator.jar'], dir: rootDir.path + '/libs/SecSettingsUITests.jar')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.3'
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:7.11.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:7.11.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-android:4.10.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-jvm-deps:1.0.6'
    androidTestImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-picocontainer:7.11.1'
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-core:7.11.1'
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:7.11.1'
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:7.11.1'
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-android:4.10.0'
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-jvm-deps:1.0.6'
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-picocontainer:7.11.1'
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.9.2'
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit-dep', version: '4.11', ext: 'pom'
}
//buildTypes {
//    debug {
//        debuggable true
//        minifyEnabled false
//        signingConfig signingConfigs.platform
//        crunchPngs false
//    }
//    release {
//        debuggable false
//        minifyEnabled false
//        signingConfig signingConfigs.platform
//    }
//}
//task jarWithExclusions(type: Jar) {
//    archiveFileName = "SecSettingsUITests.jar"
//    exclude("android/support/v4/app/INotificationSideChannel.class")
//}
//
//configurations {
//    jarWithExclusionsCompile.extendsFrom compile
//}

//dependencies {
//    jarWithExclusionsImplementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
//}
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs.add("-Xbootclasspath/p" + ":$rootDir/external/framework-minus-apex_intermediates.jar"
                + File.pathSeparator + "$rootDir/external/framework-atb-backward-compatibility_intermediates.jar"
                + File.pathSeparator + "$rootDir/external/framework-connectivity.com.android.tethering_intermediates.jar"
                + File.pathSeparator + "$rootDir/external/framework-mediaprovider.com.android.mediaprovider_intermediates.jar"
                + File.pathSeparator + "$rootDir/external/framework-permission.com.android.permission_intermediates.jar"
                + File.pathSeparator + "$rootDir/external/framework-permission-s.com.android.permission_intermediates.jar"
                + File.pathSeparator + "$rootDir/external/framework-sdkextensions.com.android.sdkext_intermediates.jar"
                + File.pathSeparator + "$rootDir/external/framework-statsd.com.android.os.statsd_intermediates.jar"
                + File.pathSeparator + "$rootDir/external/framework-tethering.com.android.tethering_intermediates.jar"
                + File.pathSeparator + "$rootDir/external/framework-wifi.com.android.wifi_intermediates.jar"
                + File.pathSeparator + "$rootDir/external/core-libart.com.android.art_intermediates.jar"
                + File.pathSeparator + "$rootDir/external/core-oj.com.android.art_intermediates.jar"
                + File.pathSeparator + "$rootDir/external/core-icu4j.com.android.i18n_intermediates.jar")
    }
}
```

my TestClass file is

```
package com.example.cucumberuitest;
import com.example.cucumberuitest.testutils.UiTest;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberJUnitRunner;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/androidTest/resources/features",
glue="com.example.cucumberuitest.steps"
)
public class TestClass  {

}
```

i tried running androidTest using run command and i get the error message

```
--------- beginning of main
03-20 15:08:47.937 10356 30024 30057 E TestRunner: failed: initializationError(io.cucumber.junit.CucumberJUnitRunnerBuilder)
03-20 15:08:47.937 10356 30024 30057 E TestRunner: ----- begin exception -----
03-20 15:08:47.937 10356 30024 30057 E TestRunner: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcucumber/runtime/ClassFinder;
03-20 15:08:47.937 10356 30024 30057 E TestRunner:  at io.cucumber.junit.CucumberJUnitRunnerBuilder.runnerForClass(CucumberJUnitRunnerBuilder.java:11)
03-20 15:08:47.937 10356 30024 30057 E TestRunner:  at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
03-20 15:08:47.937 10356 30024 30057 E TestRunner:  at androidx.test.internal.runner.AndroidRunnerBuilder.runnerForClass(AndroidRunnerBuilder.java:143)
03-20 15:08:47.937 10356 30024 30057 E TestRunner:  at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
03-20 15:08:47.937 10356 30024 30057 E TestRunner:  at androidx.test.internal.runner.DirectTestLoader.doCreateRunner(DirectTestLoader.java:45)
03-20 15:08:47.937 10356 30024 30057 E TestRunner:  at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.getRunnersFor(TestLoader.java:64)
03-20 15:08:47.937 10356 30024 30057 E TestRunner:  at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.build(TestRequestBuilder.java:835)
03-20 15:08:47.937 10356 30024 30057 E TestRunner:  at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.buildRequest(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:650)
03-20 15:08:47.937 10356 30024 30057 E TestRunner:  at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:418)
03-20 15:08:47.937 10356 30024 30057 E TestRunner:  at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2374)
03-20 15:08:47.937 10356 30024 30057 E TestRunner: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "cucumber.runtime.ClassFinder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.base.jar", zip file "/data/app/~~V6v_6ZMLLaVjvC5wQ4Ra9A==/com.example.cucumberuitest.test-1vsAfimtVekvu-_R7wCjJA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~NQzuDUyY2yQ4bL-oARXOwA==/com.example.cucumberuitest-_D29zPy4_gbUAn2O5GOGWg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~V6v_6ZMLLaVjvC5wQ4Ra9A==/com.example.cucumberuitest.test-1vsAfimtVekvu-_R7wCjJA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~NQzuDUyY2yQ4bL-oARXOwA==/com.example.cucumberuitest-_D29zPy4_gbUAn2O5GOGWg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
03-20 15:08:47.937 10356 30024 30057 E TestRunner:  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
03-20 15:08:47.937 10356 30024 30057 E TestRunner:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
03-20 15:08:47.937 10356 30024 30057 E TestRunner:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
03-20 15:08:47.937 10356 30024 30057 E TestRunner:  ... 10 more
03-20 15:08:47.937 10356 30024 30057 E TestRunner: ----- end exception -----
03-20 15:08:47.938 10356 30024 30057 I TestRunner: finished: initializationError(io.cucumber.junit.CucumberJUnitRunnerBuilder)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcucumber/runtime/ClassFinder;
    at io.cucumber.junit.CucumberJUnitRunnerBuilder.runnerForClass(CucumberJUnitRunnerBuilder.java:11)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.AndroidRunnerBuilder.runnerForClass(AndroidRunnerBuilder.java:143)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.DirectTestLoader.doCreateRunner(DirectTestLoader.java:45)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.getRunnersFor(TestLoader.java:64)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.build(TestRequestBuilder.java:835)
    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.buildRequest(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:650)
    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:418)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2374)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "cucumber.runtime.ClassFinder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.base.jar", zip file "/data/app/~~V6v_6ZMLLaVjvC5wQ4Ra9A==/com.example.cucumberuitest.test-1vsAfimtVekvu-_R7wCjJA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~NQzuDUyY2yQ4bL-oARXOwA==/com.example.cucumberuitest-_D29zPy4_gbUAn2O5GOGWg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~V6v_6ZMLLaVjvC5wQ4Ra9A==/com.example.cucumberuitest.test-1vsAfimtVekvu-_R7wCjJA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~NQzuDUyY2yQ4bL-oARXOwA==/com.example.cucumberuitest-_D29zPy4_gbUAn2O5GOGWg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Did you find the solution, I am also having same issue